# British Victorian Trials identification

Tags: identification-request

Some time ago I read about a series of paperback books, published at the time (perhaps victorian period) that were popular amongst the upper classes which contained unusual or dramatic British court cases. Cases included interesting murders, and there was an effort to republish them recently. It was a type of [Penny Dreadful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penny_dreadful) containing court transcripts and commentary.

Can anyone identify the title of this publication?

Answer (score 1):

This [web page](http://www.noumenal.com/marc/nbt.html) describes the series *Notable British Trials* published between 1905 and 1959, which is probably what you mean, in spite of the fact that it is not Victorian *sensu stricto*.